# Deativate Pytorch Lightning Module Model Logging During Prediction

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning, pytorch-forecasting

I am trying to serve a Pytorch Forecasting model using FastAPI. I am loading the model from a checkpoint using the following code on startup:

`model = BaseModel.load_from_checkpoint(model_path)`

`model.eval()`

Although the predictions do come up fine, every time there's a new version generated in the lightining_logs folder with the hyperparameters stored in a new file after each prediction. I use the following code for the predictions:

`raw_predictions = model.predict(df, mode="raw", return_x=True)`

How can I stop logging when I serve the model for predictions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone posted the answer on [GitHub](https://github.com/jdb78/pytorch-forecasting/issues/1315#issuecomment-1565018306) around the same time I discovered it after doing lots of reading. It's not that evident, at least for me:

```
trainer_kwargs={'logger':False}
```

In the case of the code in my question the prediction part would turn into:

```
raw_predictions = model.predict(df, mode="raw", return_x=False, trainer_kwardgs=dict(accelarator="cpu|gpu", logger=False))
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi heres what i normally do

1. Save as a normal pt file pytorch lighthning is fully compatible with pytorch (of course you have to redesign from a LightningModule to a normal nn.Module class)
2. Save as onnx model

```py
from model import Model
import pytorch_lightning as pl
import torch

model:pl.LightningModule = Model()
torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'weights.pt')

# Or save to onnx
torch.onnx.export(model, (inputs), fname))
```

Comment: Although this is very useful, and thank you for your answer, it doesn't really answer my question. What I was asking is how do I turn off the log generation using the libraries I'm currently using. I'll check ONNX